# macports, cmake/make and 'dyld: Library not loaded'

Tags: cmake, makefile, macports, dylib, linkage

I recently upgraded a library I use in a project of mine (glfw-devel) with macports and now my executable is dynamically link with `lib/libglfw.3.dylib` instead of `opt/local/lib/libglfw.3.dylib` which is the actual location of the lib so I get a `dyld: Library not loaded` error.

I know how to fix this with `install-names` or with a simple copy. What I cannot understand, however, is why this happens suddenly after a simple upgrade. I haven't changed anything in my `CMakeLists.txt` (the most relevant part is below) and all the other libraries I use have correct paths. Note that there is no place in the file where I refer to `lib/`.

Could it be a macports related issue? How can I make sure that my future binaries will be compiled with the proper paths?

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++14 -stdlib=libc++ -DBOOST_LOG_USE_NATIVE_SYSLOG")
set (SOURCES       src/helper.cpp
           src/capture.cpp
           src/imageBuffer.cpp
           src/projection.cpp
           )
set (APP_SOURCES   src/main.cpp )      
set (TEST_SOURCES  src/tests.cpp
                   lib/gmock-all.cc
           lib/gtest-all.cc)
include_directories(/opt/local/include
            /usr/local/include
            /usr/local/include/gmock
            /usr/local/include/gtest
            src
            )
set (DYN_LINK       /opt/local/lib
                    /usr/local/lib)
set (STATIC_LINK    static)

set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Install")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Install")

find_package(Boost 1.59.0 COMPONENTS
                log
            log_setup
            thread
            date_time
            filesystem
            system
            program_options
            REQUIRED)     
find_package(OpenCV 3.0 REQUIRED)
if (OpenCV_FOUND)
  message( "-- OpenCV found")
endif()

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
if (OpenGL_FOUND)
  message( "-- OpenGL found")
endif()

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})

#user configuration
if(${CMAKE_LINKAGE} MATCHES Static)
  message("-- STATIC LINKAGE SELECTED")
  link_directories(${STATIC_LINK})
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)
  set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES   ".a")
  set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES OFF)
else()
  message("-- DYNAMIC LINKAGE SELECTED")
  #find libraries
  link_directories(${DYN_LINK})
  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DBOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK")
  set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
endif()

if(${CMAKE_BUILD_MODE} MATCHES Release)
  message("-- RELEASE MODE ON")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")
else()
  message("-- DEBUG MODE ON")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g -DDEBUG")
endif()

# core
add_library(core ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(core ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(core ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(core ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(core GLEW)
target_link_libraries(core glfw)
```

Comment: `DYN_LINK` shows `.../lib`..., also `TEST_SOURCES`

Comment: TEST_SOURCES are only linked against the unit tests, not my main program which also has the same problem..  DYN_LINK is only /opt/local/lib and /usr/local/lib as far as I see

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. And It took me hours to figure it out.
It turned out that this problem is glfw version concerned. glfw version 3.1 is ok. Try it.

Or the bug had been posted in Macports buglist: [glfw @3.2: install_name is not set properly](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/51618)