# CMake does not link glfw right under osx

Tags: cmake, macports, glfw

20160614:

I have glfw installed by MacPorts.
`sudo port install glfw`
And I have checked that /opt/local/lib/libglfw.dylib is exists.

Here is my top header of main.cpp:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

My CMakeLists.txt(file1):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (t1)
include_directories(/opt/local/include)
link_directories(/opt/local/lib)
# find_library(MYGLFWLIB NAMES glfw HINTS /opt/local/lib NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
set(GLLIBS GL glfw glew)
add_executable(t1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(t1 ${GLLIBS})
```

After `cmake . && make` which is no error reported, I execute by `./t1`
Then Error came:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libglfw.3.dylib
Referenced from:    /Users/...../t1
Reason: image not found
[1]    13949 trace trap  ./t1
```

Then I use `otool -L t1` to check lib dependens in t1

```
/opt/local/lib/libGL.1.dylib (compatibility version 4.0.0, current version 4.0.0)
lib/libglfw.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.2.0)
/opt/local/lib/libGLEW.1.13.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.13.0, current version 1.13.0)
/usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Could someone tell me why glfw is not linked rightly?

20160615:

After modifying my CMakeLists.txt(file2):

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

project (t1)

include_directories(/opt/local/include)
link_directories(/opt/local/lib)

find_library(GL_LIB GL HINTS /opt/local/lib )
find_library(GLFW_LIB glfw HINTS /opt/local/lib)
find_library(GLEW_LIB glew HINTS /opt/local/lib)

message(${GLFW_LIB})
message(${GLEW_LIB})
message(${GL_LIB})

add_executable(t1 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(t1 ${GL_LIB} ${GLFW_LIB} ${GLEW_LIB})
```

I have two osx device(MacMini and MacBookPro), the version of MacPorts and Xcode and CMake and System are all the same:

Mac osx : 10.11.5
MacPorts 2.3.4
CMake :3.5.2 
Xcode: 7.3

Both version of CMakeLists (file1 and file2 above)works in MacMini, linker works fine.
But when it cames to my MacBookPro, glfw is not linked well.

Someone else had encounter the almost same problem:

[macports-cmake-make-dyld-library-not-loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35324332/macports-cmake-make-and-dyld-library-not-loaded)

Is this problem SYSTEM VARIABLE concerned ?

Answer (score 2):

After search for hours, I found the reason : [glfw @3.2: install_name is not set properly](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/51618)

Comment: You can fix this for now using `sudo install_name_tool -id /opt/local/lib/libglfw.3.dylib /opt/local/lib/libglfw.3.dylib`. This will change the install name of the library to the correct value.

Comment: Thanks. I knew that install_name_tool can correct value, I just want to know how this happend. Anyway, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
set(GLLIBS GL glfw glew)
```

That's not how you should use CMake. Use `find_library` or

```
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(simple ${GLFW_LIBRARIES})
```

Have a look into the documentation:
http://www.glfw.org/docs/3.0/build.html

Comment: Following your advice, I use `find_library` to find libglfw.dylib path. 

`find_library(GLFW_LIB glfw HINTS /opt/local/lib)`. 

By `message(${GLFW_LIB})`,  cmake find the glfw lib which located in /opt/loca/lib/libglfw.dylib , but still the generated binary file reported error:

dyld: Library not loaded: lib/libglfw.3.dylib

Comment: Use `message` for printing the values of `GLFW_LIBRARIES`. Maybe also delete the CMakeCache.txt file.

Comment: The method of deleting unrelated files(CMakeCache.txt...) had been tried, nothing miracle happened. By `message` I can see the GLFW_LIB is right: /opt/local/lib/libglfw.3.dylib, but when it goes the binary, something wrong happened. I realy want to know what make the differences.